# Hive - find 2 characters anywhere in the string/row - RLIKE

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, sql-like, regexp-like

How do I get the data for ONLY “_WA”  data assigned to "USA_RBB_WA_BU"? 
However the column I look at has rows that contain _WA and _SA (USA_CA_SAWANT)

I used,

```
                        select....
                         'USA_RBB_WA_BU' AS State ,
                         District 
                         from TABLE where district like '%_WA%'


                        select   ...
                         'USA_RBB_NSW_BU' AS State ,
                         District 
                         from TABLE where district like '%_SA%'
```

however I ended up with data output table below

```
**state                  district**
USA_RBB_NSW_BU          USA_CA_SAWANT
USA_RBB_WA_BU           USA_CA_SAWANT
USA_RBB_NSW_BU          USA_CA_SAWANT
USA_RBB_WA_BU           USA_CA_SAWANT
```

I tried

```
                        select....
                         'USA_RBB_WA_BU' AS State ,
                         District 
                         from TABLE where district like '_WA%'

                         output was  was 0 results in hive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where district rlike '_WA'` will work fine (this will return TRUE if string contains _WA)

If you want string to contain something before and after `_WA`, add `.+` (any character one or more times):

```
where district rlike '.+_WA.+'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However,The output was 0 results for this. I am looking for is "_WA" anywhere in the string. When matching it should NOT take just "WA" instead match exactly "_WA"  My code above finds "WA" its wrong because "USA_CA_SAWANT" should be part of  "from TABLE where district like '%_SA%'". thanks for your input

Comment: @YJG `rlike '_WA'` works exactly according to your requirement - "_WA" anywhere in the string.

Comment: Thanks for the response and Yes   = where district rlike '_WA' works exactly as intended. My bad I only noticed the  where district rlike '.+_WA.+' on your answer before. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for escaping `_`  here. Try below -

```
SELECT <FIELD_LIST>
       'USA_RBB_WA_BU' AS State ,
       District 
FROM TABLE
WHERE district RLIKE '.*_WA%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ankit. However,The output was 0 results for this like leftjoin . I am looking for is "_WA" anywhere in the string. When matching it should NOT take just "WA" instead match exactly "_WA"  My code above finds "WA" its wrong because "USA_CA_SAWANT" should be part of  "from TABLE where district like '%_SA%'". thanks for your input